# Rename [twitter-integration] tag to [twitter]

Tags: discussion, retagging

We currently have 10 questions tagged [twitter-integration](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-integration). There is no [twitter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) tag. I can't think of any WordPress + Twitter questions that will not be about how to "integrate" them (either by sending WP content to Twitter or by using Twitter content on your WP site), so I propose we just shorten the tag to [twitter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter).

Comment: Seems valid... +1.

Comment: Similar case: [wordpress-3.0.1](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-3.0.1) could be renamed to wordpress-3.0.

Comment: @toscho - I'd ask does [wordpress-3.0](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-3.0) even make sense? Is it really useful? Most questions are bout WordPress 3.0 yet most don't have that tag. Maybe I should ask that ask another meta question? *(BTW, too bad SE doesn't have a list of categories like WordPress where we could have ~10 major categories for the site)*

Comment: Some question may be specific to 3.0 (bugs in new features that are fixed in 3.1). I doubt it, but it is possible.   Really bad is the tag [wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress). We have already more than 460 tags. Way too much, in my opinion. So, yes, we should search for redundant tags and clean them up as long as this is still possible.

Comment: @Mike: We once [discussed how to tag questions that relate to functionality new in WordPress 3.0](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tag-for-wordpress-3). Maybe we can re-use that discussion, or do you open a new one?

Comment: @Jan Fabry - I commented over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good idea! I renamed [twitter-integration](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-integration) to [twitter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter), so this is now completed.